# Record is Unavailable error opening attachments in Annotation- Dynamics CRM

Tags: internet-explorer, dynamics-crm, internet-explorer-11, dynamics-crm-2013

I am relatively new to Microsoft CRM and have a client who is using CRM 2013 RU3, who is having intermittent issues downloading annotation attachments. They receive the following error:
[image]

I found a good article that explains the issue [here](http://blog.craigharvey.me/2016/01/20/record-is-unavailable-error-opening-attachment-in-notes-dynamics-crm/) but with no solution. It is not possible to use another browser as the company has a policy that enforces the use of IE11. 
I was thinking one way would be to disable caching for all attachments but I have no idea if this is even possible? Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Boden